# Visual studio sp1 error: RiaServices.msi is unavailable

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-2010

I'm have been trying to install the sp1 for visual studio 2010. I have first downloaded vm_web and Silverlight4_Tools, both of which seemed to install fine.

I tried to open VS2010 and got the error,

Only some of the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 products on this computer have been upgraded to Service Pack 1. None will work correctly until all have been upgraded.

Then it shows a prompt to download and install SP1.
I downloaded this file, ran the installer and solved the issue with finding the silverlight_sdk.msi file.

I cannot however resolve the issue with the RiaSerivices.msi file. I have trawled the net (apparently a common error) and tried

1) to download RiaServices.msi seperately and point to the file in the downloads folder. 
2) I have also tried to move the RiaServices.msi file to the installation folder (in my case C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_10.0.40219) as was suggested in another question

Still not working. The error I get is,

The file 'file path...' is not a valid installation package for the product WCF RIA Services V1.0 SP1. Try to find the installation package 'RiaServices.msi' in a folder from which you can install WCF RIA Services V1.0 SP1.

Any ideas?

Comment: yep, having the very same problem, to the dot.

Comment: Yeah seems to be a common problem, but all the fixes I found dont work. I have currently reverted back on my comp to before the install until I find a fix. If you do find anything, please share. Ta :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to download Ria services from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14880)

Setup will be completed.

I was also facing same issue but by downloading Ria services from this location problem is resolved.

Comment: I also have this problem but it keeps telling me RiaServices is already installed and I can't seem to find where it is, apparently neither can my Service Pack...

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem. I went from a situation like that.
I've installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_10.0.40219 from disk f, and I asked the installer RiaServices.msi presence in the temporary folder C: \ Users \ user1 \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_10.0.40219. But I noticed that the disk was created f temporary folder. And here's where I put him RiaServices.msi. And the installer earned as needed. Maybe this will help to someone. From SW. marina

Answer (score 0):

For future Googlers: I had the same issue, but with vstor40_x64.msi. [This MS fix-it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall) solved it for me. I was pulling my hair out for a couple days so I want to save some pain for anyone else unfortunate enough to be stuck with VS2010 for legacy systems!

Choose the option "I'm having trouble installing a program" and pick whichever component it's tripping on--in my case VS 2010 Tools for Office Runtime, in your case Ria Services. Then SP1 should succeed. You may need to repeat for other partially-installed components.